# Long running Daemon on Android - Best Approach

Tags: android, android-ndk, serial-port, daemon

I have an android target tablet that will be deployed to a vehicle. The tablet will be connected to two serial devices and needs to have a process on board that will send periodic readings,once every 4 seconds from one serial device and every other minute from the other serial device, back to a web server via a REST call. The tablet will also run a web app, related to but not connected to the process monitoring the serial ports. The serial port process has to be running ALL the time and meeting the SLA of sending data every 3 seconds.

As an android noob my readings so far suggest that since android 8 the battery optimization  *improvements* from google have largely led to background services loosing their ability to be long running and background. I have seen several approaches (look like hacks) to circumvent this. At the tablet level I think there is a real use case and need for a long running daemon.

My question is to appeal to those with experience as to the best approach here. Am I better to use the Service API in java and build a background service or is the best approach to deploy an NDK C++ exe?

The Service API is not part of the NDK API so I assume I have posix threads to work with in C++?
Do I still deploy an APK? Rooting the device is NOT an option.

I cannot find use cases that match what I am trying to do, and as an android new comer, the hope is that people who have spend years using the various API's I refer to will shed some hard won experience on this issue saving me significant effort and time.

Answer (score 1):

If the process doesn't need to be guaranteed (in the case of the device going offline for example) but is not deferrable, a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/foreground-services) would work well.

Foreground services are capable of achieving what you would want probably, but they will display a running notification for as long as they are active. Swiping the notification would kill the service. Power cycling would as well. Still, it is a good solution, provided the user is cognizant of the importance that it remains running.

Regardless of whether you use foreground services or some other solution, your app may request to be ignored by battery optimizations. [Source.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS)

An example of how you can do this:

```
String packageName = context.getPackageName();
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

and ensure that

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```

is in your app's manifest. [This permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS) is not considered `dangerous`.

Comment: Can more than one app on android be active at a time? The browser based app will be the main app with the input focus pretty much all the time. Does that mean in android that the serial port reading app is no longer foreground? If so then this might not be a solution. Otherwise it has potential. Thx.

Comment: The piece of information I have failed to  supply is that the tablet will be mains powered. With this in mind is the Android OS likely to invoke battery management when on mains power? Meaning are the restrictions on long running background processes ONLY a battery powered device concern or do I still need to take them into account in our case?

Comment: Further to this the target tablet is Zebra, and I note that Doze can be disabled on Zebra, so I think this might clear the way to having a long running daemon process in java on android. My understanding is that Doze is the system app that kills long running tasks consuming battery resources. Anyone see any faults in this reasoning?

Comment: @user2118159 The service would just be analogous to a background process. The activity that launched it and the service itself are part of the same app (e.g. share the same declared permissions in the app manifest). With foreground services, after being launched, even if the launching activity is killed or not in focus, the service will continue to run.

So natively your app would most likely be composed of both an activity and a service. The activity would be the web app you describe, the service would continuously perform serial operations. Does this help?